# How to explain the crash report?

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, crash-reports

My app was rejected, but I don't know what's the problem.

Rejected reason is:

We found that your app crashed on iPhone 4 running iOS 5.0.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Your app crashed on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks

when we:

1) Launch the app connected to a Wi-Fi or cellular network
2) The app crashes.

But, I test the my app withe iphone 4 running ios 5.0.1 which didn't come out crash like that, so I'm confused, plz help me, thanks a million.

```
Incident Identifier: AAA90ABE-B2F1-483A-97B8-2990DF83698C
CrashReporter Key:   52a7dd4ac386930f5f86a0b0e9b2de47158609a3
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:        *****
Path:           *******
Identifier:      *****
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]


Date/Time:       2012-01-26 17:51:05.914 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fd832c 0x35fc7000 + 70444
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32ea1f54 0x32e54000 + 319316
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e9afe4 0x32e54000 + 290788
3   libc++abi.dylib                0x334e4f64 0x334de000 + 28516
4   libc++abi.dylib                0x334e23ea 0x334de000 + 17386
5   libc++abi.dylib                0x334e244a 0x334de000 + 17482
6   libc++abi.dylib                0x334e381e 0x334de000 + 22558
7   libobjc.A.dylib                0x3430d22e 0x34304000 + 37422
8   CoreFoundation                 0x3401353e 0x34004000 + 62782
9   CoreFoundation                 0x3401339e 0x34004000 + 62366
10  GraphicsServices               0x30897fc6 0x30894000 + 16326
11  UIKit                          0x3749473c 0x37463000 + 202556
12  *******（app's name）                         0x00003e74 0x1000 + 11892
13  *******                         0x00003e2c 0x1000 + 11820





Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fc83b4 0x35fc7000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib              0x36cf2e78 0x36ce6000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib              0x36cf2b96 0x36ce6000 + 52118


Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 2:
0   DataDetectorsCore              0x37a54828 0x37a4e000 + 26664
1   DataDetectorsCore              0x37a5456c 0x37a4e000 + 25964
2   DataDetectorsCore              0x37a51b90 0x37a4e000 + 15248
3   DataDetectorsCore              0x37a520b8 0x37a4e000 + 16568
4   DataDetectorsCore              0x37a50da8 0x37a4e000 + 11688
5   DataDetectorsUI                0x34613db6 0x3460e000 + 23990
6   Foundation                     0x35a2e39c 0x35a03000 + 177052
7   Foundation                     0x35a9779c 0x35a03000 + 608156
8   libdispatch.dylib              0x36ce6d4e 0x36ce6000 + 3406
9   libdispatch.dylib              0x36cf279c 0x36ce6000 + 51100
10  libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e1c8 0x32e54000 + 41416
11  libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e09c 0x32e54000 + 41116


Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fc8010 0x35fc7000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fc8206 0x35fc7000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                 0x3409141c 0x34004000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                 0x34090154 0x34004000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                 0x340134d6 0x34004000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                 0x3401339e 0x34004000 + 62366
6   WebCore                        0x364e7128 0x3643f000 + 688424
7   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e63c16 0x32e54000 + 64534
8   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e63ad0 0x32e54000 + 64208


Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fd8cd4 0x35fc7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e30a 0x32e54000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e09c 0x32e54000 + 41116


Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fc8010 0x35fc7000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fc8206 0x35fc7000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                 0x3409141c 0x34004000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                 0x34090154 0x34004000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                 0x340134d6 0x34004000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                 0x3401339e 0x34004000 + 62366
6   Foundation                     0x35a13bc2 0x35a03000 + 68546
7   Foundation                     0x35a13a8a 0x35a03000 + 68234
8   Foundation                     0x35aa759a 0x35a03000 + 673178
9   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e63c16 0x32e54000 + 64534
10  libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e63ad0 0x32e54000 + 64208


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fd8cd4 0x35fc7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e30a 0x32e54000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e09c 0x32e54000 + 41116


Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fd8cd4 0x35fc7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e30a 0x32e54000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e09c 0x32e54000 + 41116


Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fd8570 0x35fc7000 + 71024
1   CoreFoundation                 0x3409566a 0x34004000 + 595562
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e63c16 0x32e54000 + 64534
3   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e63ad0 0x32e54000 + 64208


Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x35fd8cd4 0x35fc7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e30a 0x32e54000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x32e5e09c 0x32e54000 + 41116


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3e78bce8      r6: 0x00000002      r7: 0x2fdffb1c
    r8: 0x3f448d6c    r9: 0x334e5a32     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x3f448d6c
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdffb10      lr: 0x32ea1f5b      pc: 0x35fd832c
  cpsr: 0x00070010
```

Comment: Did you test on the actual device or simulator?

Comment: Of course, I did. Same test environment like they said, but no crash in mine.

Comment: Try and download the crash log provided by Apple and drag and drop it into Xcode so it can be symbolicated and you should get a better picture of what's going on. Also from experience apps are tested in devices setup with different languages and environments. I had an app rejected once because of crashes that would only happen on non English phones which was something we never considered testing with.

Comment: Thanks rog, that's helped, I will try.

Comment: @Rog so what if I don't want my app sold in non english phones. Can I say it is a restriction. Just like we say what min iOS version is needed

Comment: You still have to make it work cause I could be living in a English speaking country and have my phone setup to my native language.

Answer (score 1):

1) If you are not using ARC, convert your project to ARC.  That will make crashes like this much less likley.

2) To see where in your code you crashed, you need to desymbolicate the crash log so it will show you where in your code the call that crashed came from.  Try following these instructions:

[Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports/2673058#2673058)

Comment: The linked answer for how to symbolicate manually is not correct, see my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports#comment21083015_4954949

Comment: I think the best answer there is to import the crash log into Organizer, where XCode should use the dsym file to de-symbolicate.

Comment: Are you referencing to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2673058/474794 Yes, thats the better answer. I suggest editing your link to point right at the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=iPhone3,1), iPhone3,1 is the GSM model of the iPhone 4.

Did you test with a GSM model, or a CDMA model? This crash may only happen with the GSM model.

Comment: Yes, we're GSM model. Thus, CDMA u mentioned is exactly a problem. I will try this. Thanks.